# Apache-poi template leading zeros disappear on editing cells

Tags: java, apache-poi, dataformat, leading-zero

I'm creating a .xlsx template using apache-poi, the user have to insert an id that has fixed length.

i've already tried the setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("@")) trick, but when the cell is edited it seems to forget that, and leading zeros disappear.

```
//this is the code snippet i found here on stackoverflow and tried out
DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
textStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
worksheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);
```

It would be great finding a true solution, because adding leading zeros to get the expected length can cause errors. Ex: user means 0000111 but forgets a 1 , new id will be 0000011 and unfortunately ids aren't sequential.

Thanks for your time, and forgive me for my bad english XD

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your issue.

Following code creates a `Excel` sheet having Ids in column `A` which are not losing their text format and leading zeros even if edited in `Excel`s `GUI`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelNumberFormatText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   textStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);

   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(textStyle);
   cell.setCellValue("Id");

   cell = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(textStyle);
   cell.setCellValue("0000111");

   cell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(textStyle);
   cell.setCellValue("0001111");

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

What you probably not expected is that `apache poi` does not applying the column style to new created cells in that column. This you needs doing in code else the cell style will be `General`. Setting the column style is nevertheless necessary since else `Excel`s `GUI` will not use the text style while adding cell contents there.

My code is complete, tested and works for me. Simply editing the cells in `Excel` cannot lead to lost of  parts of cell contents (the leading zeros) because of using the number format `@ = Text`.

Of course, if someone changes the column number format from `Text` to `General`, then `0000111` will be the number `111` after editing. But this is cannot be prevented when the sheet is editable by the user.

Maybe one could set [CellStyle.setQuotePrefixed](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed-boolean-) additionally. As:

```
...
   textStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
   textStyle.setQuotePrefixed(true);
...
```

Then all content will be prefixed with a quote prefix apostrophe `'` additionally. But this too can be changed by a user editing the sheet.

Comment: unfortunatly this is exactly the trick i meant, and doesn't work in my case. when the user goes to write on template leading zeros disappear

Comment: @NicoloB91:  See my supplements.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. I'll try and evaluate pros and cons of the ' solution as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me :

```java
cell = row.createCell(col, CellType.STRING);
cell.setCellValue(val);
```